# Saving values when closing app or switching fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android and have an integer weekNumber that needs to be kept when closing the app. My idea was to set the value in the activity that handled the fragments that need to use the value, and always get the value from there with a getter, but the weekNumber keeps resetting when I close the app or switch fragments, even though I use SharedPreferences. I load the saved data in onCreate of the activity, and save the data in onPause. Maybe this is wrong. Why does this happen? I would appreciate any help and would love to learn more!

Here is my MainActivity that handles Fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int weekNumber;

private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
private static final String WEEK_NUMBER = "weekNumber";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

    loadData();

    }

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_add:
                        selectedFragment = new CalculatorFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        selectedFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveData();
}

public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(WEEK_NUMBER,weekNumber);
    }

public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
    weekNumber = sharedPreferences.getInt(WEEK_NUMBER,1);
}

public int getWeekNumber() {
    return weekNumber;
}

public void setWeekNumber(int weekNumber) {
    this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
}
```

One of the Fragments:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;

private TextView[] textViews;

MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

    textViews = new TextView[16];

    for(int i=0; i<textViews.length; i++) {
        {
            String buttonID = "textView" + (i+1);

            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
            textViews[i] = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(resID));
        }
    }

    setWeekText();

    textViews[9].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityDay1.class));
        }
    });

    Button buttonNextWeek = rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonNextWeek);
    buttonNextWeek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainActivity.setWeekNumber(mainActivity.getWeekNumber()+1);
            setWeekText();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void setWeekText() {
    textViews[8].setText(String.valueOf(mainActivity.getWeekNumber()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `editor.apply();` at the end of your `saveData` function in order to actually save the value in the SharedPreferences.

Also, you can't call `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` in the fragment. Set it with `mainActivity = getActivity();` in onCreateView or directly in your onClick listeners.

Why? What you have creates a new instance of MainActivity inside the fragment rather than referring to the one on which you have set the data you need.

Also, if you keep the current design, it's probably safer to call `loadData` in your Activity `onCreate` *before* you create the fragment that is going to try to access the data.

Perhaps a better option would be to just use the shared preferences in the fragment directly though.

Comment: This did not work sadly. The same problem applies, but thank you anyways

Comment: That now worked as a charm. Thank you so much! I understand the concept of using getActivity() instead, but why does `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity` not refer to the one I keep my data in? Is this only the case with Fragments?

Comment: When you call that, it creates a new instance of MainActivity inside your fragment. It's not displayed, so none of its lifecycle methods are called (`onCreate`, `onPause`, etc...). It has its own instance of `weekNumber`, but never calls `loadData` or `saveData` so the value you set there is not kept.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. You need to make sure data is actually being saved. Add `editor.commit()`in your `saveData()`
2. You should do the saving in `onSaveInstance` and restoring in `onSaveInstance` since this is what android will call when the system kill your activity on cases such as low memory